# 2bit bit-fields array effects on performance and cache efficiency?

Tags: c++, performance, caching, bit-fields, memory-efficient

I am in need of a 2bit array, I am not concerned with saving memory at all, but I am concerned with minimizing cache misses and maximizing cache efficiency. Using an array of bools will use 4 times more memory, which means for every usable chunk of data in the cache, there will be 3 that are not used. So technically, I can get 3 times better cache consistency if I use bitfields.

The plan is to implement it as an array of bytes, divided into 4 equal bitfields, and use the div function to be able to get the integral quotient and remainder, possibly in a single clock, and use those to access the right index and right bitfield.

The array I needs is about 10000 elements long, so it will make for a significantly denser packed data, using 2 actual bits will allow for the entire array to fit in L1 cache, while using a byte array this will not be possible.

So my question is whether someone can tell me if this is a good idea in a performance oriented task, so I know if it is worth to go forth and implement a 2bit array? And surely, the best way to know is profiling, but any information in advance may be useful and will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for? You seem to already know what you want and that profiling will help you get it.

Comment: @sftrabbit - known issues, potential pitfalls, basic ideas how having 4 times better data density in the L1 cache will play out against the extra cost of having such a data structure.

Comment: Yes -- it's likely that your code will run faster with the bits packed. Since they're bit-wise anyway, it's probably cleaner to use bit-wise operators (`&`, `|`) instead of division and remainder to do the packing and unpacking.

Comment: Avoid the div function. Compilers can see it when you compute both / and %. I would just use bitfields `struct A4 { unsigned char x1:2; etc }` and let the compiler handle optimization.

Comment: Avoid single-byte accesses. Try to use integers with 32 or even 64 bits as underlying storage. The reason is that this puts less stress on the memory bus, which requires special processing to access single bytes in most modern systems. Also, most CPUs have register with 32 or 64 bits, so that's the natural unit of computation anyway.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I don't know if it's still the case, but the last time I looked (a very long time ago, I'll admit), compilers didn't implement bitfields particularly efficiently.  And of course, you cannot create an array of bitfields.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I was wondering about that myself.  I'd almost certainly write it using bit manipulators, but then, I come from a hardware background.  I don't know what other people would think with regards to readability.  (The compiler will almost certainly generate exactly the same code either way.)

Comment: Of course you make an array of n/4 structs that each contain 4 bitfields (possibly replace 4 with more). As long as you remain in the general case (read the bitfields independently) I would trust the compiler to generate the right code (I would also trust it to recognize & | >> patterns as bitfield extractions).

Comment: I agree that it is hard to answer without at least some idea of how the array will be used.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I may have a *little* of the same "problem", but it certainly seems to me that `x & 0x03` is a clearer way to say "the two least significant bits of x" than using division and remainder, but I *suppose* others might disagree (I suppose, especially those with more background in math and less in hardware).

Answer (score 5):

With 10000 elements, on a modern processor, it should fit nicely in memory as bytes (10KB), so I wouldn't worry too much about it, unless you want this to run on some very tiny microprocessor with a cache that is much smaller than the typical 16-32KB L1 caches that modern CPU's have.

Of course, you may well want to TEST the performance with different solutions, if you think this is an important part of your code from a performance perspective [as measured from your profiling that you've already done before you start optimising, right?].

Comment: But which cache?  L3 cache _is_ often (but not always) 10KB; L1 is smaller, but faster.  And of course, on the other side, how much does accessing on non-byte boundaries cost.  For random access, it may cost more that the loss due to going out a level or two in the cache.

Comment: On what processor? On modern Intel/AMD cpu's the L2 cache is 512K or 1MB, L3 caches are larger. L1 cache on AMD cpu's are typically 64+64KB, on Intel CPU's, it's typically 32+32KB (sandy/ivy bridge for example). ARM15 processors have 32+32KB.

Comment: Most modern processors indeed have 32kb of data cache, but it is still shared with every running process, thus my intent to minimize the footprint as much as possible. The array is used as a lookup table in a text parser.

Comment: Yes, of course. The point is rather, which is most efficient: reading a single byte or shuffling bits around. Shuffling bits is definitely more expensive from the CPU's perspective, as you end up with at least an "and" and a "shift" instructio to dig out the correct bits. So I suspect, in a reasonably good case, it's slower. I'm sure that it's possible to come up with a scenario of another process running and only polluting cache-entries that aren't "your table", but it's unlikely to be a common case - if another process gets to run, cache is gone.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me that this will result in a performance
gain.  Accessing each field will require several instructions
(`(data[i / 4] >> 2 * (i % 4)) & 0x03`), and a lot of modern
processors have an L3 cache which would hold the entire array
with one byte per entry.  Whether the extra cost in execution
time will be greater or less than the difference in caching is
hard to say; you'll have to profile to know exactly.

If you can organize your algorithms to work a byte (or even a
word) at a time, the cost of access may be much less.  Iterating
over the entire array, for example:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; i += 4 ) {
    unsigned char w1 = data[ i / 4 ];
    for ( int j = 0; j < 4; ++ j ) {
        unsigned char w2 = w1 & 0x03;
        //  w2 is entry i + j...
        w1 >>= 2;
    }
}
```

could make a significant difference.  Most compilers will be
able to keep `w1` and `w2` in registers, meaning you'll only
have 1/4 as many memory accesses.  Packing withunsigned int`
would probably be even faster.

Comment: Fixed minor typo: `w1 >>= 4` should be `w1 >>= 2`.

Comment: I would also avoid i/4 and use i >> 2 - that way, the compiler will DEFINITELY use shifts, rather than potentinally use other mecahnisms to divide.

Comment: @Mats Petersson But using `/` lets the compiler do the division in the most efficient manner while `>>` restricts it to one particular mechanism that may not always be faster.

Comment: As discussed in a different thread, if you use / the compiler HAS to follow the rules of dividing negative numbers [in this case, it may realize that `i` is never negative, but not always], and this means that what is one instruction with `>>`, becomes about five instructions on x86_64. I tried it. Do that yourself if you don't trust me.

Comment: This is all about bit manipulations, so I dare hope no one would even think of using a signed type here. As a remark, for signed types, *4 is faster than <<2 (more undefined behavior on overflow).

Comment: @MatsPetersson Actually, performance would argue using division.  Division is more used in general, and so is what the compilers optimize most.  But in practice, I can't imagine a compiler ever generating different code.

Comment: @MarcGlisse There is _no_ bit manipulation on the index, and no justifiable reason to use anything other than `int` for it.

Comment: I will let you try it out for yourself. Make sure the compiler can't just constant substitute, and look at the assembler code. Certainly both gcc and clang (and their C++ siblings) generate more complicated code for `x / 2^y` than `x >> y`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Not for unsigned values on my Linux box.

Comment: Correct. But the code above is using "int", which is a signed type.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes, but you'd never want to use shift and masking on an `int`, because of the confusion it would cause.

Comment: Is this one of those language lawyer type things, as I have MANY examples of that where I work like the Linux source code... It appears to work fairly well there... Of course, it's not meant to run on ANY hardware - it only runs on a few dozen different models of processors, and sometimes there are bugs found in the code for rare and obscure hardware.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Where it fails is when some one else has to maintain the code.  (And I certainly wouldn't take the Linux source code as a reference for robust and maintainable code, at least not the parts I've seen.)