# Byte Array to Hex Digits (0 to 9 and A to F only)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, std

I am trying to convert a "double" value (say 1.12345) to 8 byte hex string. I am using the following function to convert double value to hex string.

```
std::string double_to_hex_string(double d)
{
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char*)&d;
const int bufferSize = sizeof(double);

char converted[bufferSize * 2 + 1];
//char converted[bufferSize];

int j = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < bufferSize ; ++i)
{
    sprintf(&converted[j*2], "%02X", buffer[i]);
    ++j;
}
string hex_string(converted);
return hex_string;
}
```

This function returns the 16 byte hex string. I then compress this string to fit into 8 bytes through this code

```
string hexStr = double_to_hex_string(TempD);

unsigned char sample[8];

for ( int i = 0; i < hexStr.length() / 2 ; i++) 
{
sscanf( (hexStr.substr(i*2,2)).c_str(), "%02X", &sample[i]);
}
```

Now, how can I get the hex digits representing these 8 bytes in "sample" array. There should be only one hex digit per byte. I need to append this 8 byte hex string to a global string.

If there is any other solution which can convert a double value to 8 hex digits and vice versa, that would be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: How do you expect to get "one hex digit per byte"? A hex digit can only encode 16 values while a byte holds 256. If you need to make it smaller but still with readable characters, look into [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: What are you *trying* to do?  Does your "global" string need to be readable or have some specific format?  If not, you could just copy the 8 bytes of the `double` directly to the string.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes, the global string has a specific format. I have to store the double value into 8 bytes and each of these 8 bytes must represent a hex digit. Later on, these 8 bytes should be converted back to double value.

Comment: @WaqasDanish A `double` is typically 8 bytes to begin with.  You'll need 16 hex digits to store the value exactly.

Comment: What about if I cast the double to float (4 bytes)?

Comment: @WaqasDanish That would work.  With reduced accuracy, of course.  Your current compression code overwrites each byte and overflows the `sample` array, because `sscanf` is writing to multiple bytes each time.  You can not get the original double back from the 8 bytes you've produced.

Comment: " how can I get the hex digits representing these 8 bytes in "sample" array. " Erm, you had them just a minute ago!

Comment: I had a simple requirement, but only for 2bit array, you could use the same strategies for a 4bit array as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427715/2bit-bit-fields-array-effects-on-performance-and-cache-efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hexidecimal digit represents *half a byte*, so if you are limited to 8 hex digits you are also limited to storing 4 bytes.

This solution will encode the number from a `float`, which is commonly 4 bytes.

```
std::string double_to_hex_string(double d)
{
    // Create a stream that writes 2 digit hex values
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::hex << std::setfill('0');

    float f = d;
    const unsigned char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>( &f );
    const unsigned char *buffer_end = buffer + sizeof(f);

    // Write each byte as 2 character hex.
    while ( buffer != buffer_end )
    {
      stream << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>( *buffer );
      ++buffer;
    }

    return stream.str();
}
```

Comment: Evidently `std::setw` isn't sticky, you need to set it again for each byte.

Comment: Yes, the idea was to convert the double to float. Thanks DrewDormann